# How to create an ATL class that implements CDialogImpl and IPreviewFrameHandler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, atl

I'm trying to create a dialog that hosts a file preview handler.  I started by creating an ATL dialog (through the Visual Studio menu), which derives from `CDialogImpl`, so that part was pretty straightforward.

But I've now learned that hosting a preview handler involves implementing `IPreviewHandlerFrame`.  So I guess I have to derive from that, implement its methods, and implement `IUnknown` as well.  And then I guess that the dialog needs to be created via `CoCreateInstance`?  (Not sure about that part.)

So I'm not sure if I should go back and start over, instead creating an ATL Object that derives from `CDialogImpl` and `IPreviewHandlerFrame`.  That would involve all of the ATL registration and everything, and I'm not sure if that's necessary .  Or is it better just to add the `IUnknown` methods?  But even so, how would the class be instantiated?  I'm not sure I want to interfere in the ref-counting or anything like that.

Thanks for any guidance on how to do this.

Or maybe another approach would be to implement `IPreviewHandlerFrame` in its own ATL class, and then instantiate it in the `CDialogImpl`?

Comment: Basically, you need a Preview Handler "site" object. This object can be quite independent from the dialog (a UI oriented object), Just create another ATL object with needed interfaces. You should never have to implement IUnknown yourself if you use ATL.